# Posting a request throws Connection pool error in java

Tags: java, sql

I'm getting connection pool issue when I try to post to the Database

here what I'm using for context xml file

```
 factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    maxActive="10" 
    initialSize="0"
    maxAge="1800"
    testWhileIdle="true"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    testOnReturn="false"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    validationInterval="30000"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    logAbandoned="true"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="18000"
    jmxEnabled="true"
    fairQueue="true"
    jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
                        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer;
                        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
```

the Error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-3] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:10; busy:10; idle:0; lastwait:30000].
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:710) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:132) ~[tomcat-jdbc.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
```

I have this working working before, then suddenly it stops working, Is there something I'm missing to add or update in my config?

Comment: What you are missing is to release connections after you use them causing connection pool to drain.

Answer (score 1):

There can be different reasons why your connectionpool is exausted. If you are using a framework that connects to your mysql database check the recommended pool configuration.

Also make sure to close your connections properly.

The try-with-resources Statement: [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html#:~:text=The%20try%2Dwith%2Dresources%20Statement,the%20end%20of%20the%20statement.)

a reasonable config could look like this:

```
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
...
   initialSize="10"
   maxActive="100"
   maxIdle="50"
   minIdle="10"
...
/>
```